# Return from a function when one of try ... catch block throws an error

Tags: javascript

I've got a function where I submit a large form and it makes multiple API calls. I tried to separate it into smaller functions cause there is some additional logic that depends on API response.
I wrapped each API call within a function in `try ... catch` so that I have more control over the errors. The problem is that I need to terminate the parent function whenever one of the child function throws an error and I can't figure out the clean way of doing that.

So the code is the following:

```
const func1 = async() => {
    try {
        // api call + logic
    } catch (error) {
        // show error toast and terminate formSubmit function
    }
}

const func2 = async() => {
    try {
        // api call + logic
    } catch (error) {
        // show error toast and terminate formSubmit function
    }
}

const func3 = async() => {
    try {
        // api call + logic
    } catch (error) {
        // show error toast and terminate formSubmit function
    }
}


const formSubmit = async () => {
    await func1()
    await func2()
    await func3()
}
```

Comment: You could simply rethrow the error (or throw a new special error indicating the other error was already handled) and handle it in a `catch` in `formSubmit` with the returning.

Answer (score 1):

Just throw a new error or rethrow the error and then add a new handler in your formSubmit function.

```js
const func1 = async() => {
    try {
        // api call + logic
    } catch (error) {
        // show error toast and terminate formSubmit function
        throw new Error("...");
    }
}

const func2 = async() => {
    try {
        // api call + logic
    } catch (error) {
        // show error toast and terminate formSubmit function
        throw new Error("...");
    }
}

const func3 = async() => {
    try {
        // api call + logic
    } catch (error) {
        // show error toast and terminate formSubmit function
        throw new Error("...");
    }
}


const formSubmit = async () => {
    try {
        await func1()
        await func2()
        await func3()
    } catch(e){
       // do what needs to be done on error
    }

}
```